# Deployment from OVA format

Tags: vmware-workstation, esxi

I am deploying a VM using a OVA format. The  size of OVA format is 57 GB. Currently free space on my datastore is 388 GB.

At the time of selecting Disk Format type if shows me in red that the disk size required is 1 TB therefore you cannot select THICK provisioning.

Therefore, I selected THIN provisioning. In THIN provisioning, I am showed that Estimated Disk Usage is 112 GB which is less than the free space available.

But even after selecting THIN provisioning at the time of deployment it throws an error that it cannot create disk, as the size of disk is larger than the maximum specified limit.

My block size is of 1 MB.

Pasting my exact error here:

```
Failed to deploy OVF package:File [datastore1] IMS Tester 1/IMS Tester1_2.vmdk is larger than maximum size supported by datastore 'datastore1
```